# Problems exporting a Minecraft open-source plugin [org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError]

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I almost know anything about Java but I tried exporting an open-source Minecraft Plugin from Github into a .jar file.
I used Eclipse to export all the codes into a jar but when I tried to run the plugin it gave me errors.

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/ess3/api/MaxMoneyException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:133) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:327) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:248) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:305) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:205) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:545) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_301]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/ess3/api/MaxMoneyException
        at com.maximuspayne.navycraft.NavyCraft.<init>(NavyCraft.java:73) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:90) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:129) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ess3.api.MaxMoneyException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:152) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:100) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at com.maximuspayne.navycraft.NavyCraft.<init>(NavyCraft.java:73) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:90) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:129) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        ... 6 more
```

Here is the github page if it is needed: https://github.com/Gregory1346/NavyCraft-Reloaded

Can someone help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is clear : Some classes inside the package `net.ess3.api` are not found. You need to add this jar file into the build path

Comment: Yes, you need essentials

Answer (score 1):

The error log say it failed to find a class. Here, it's not a class from your jar, so you have to find where it should be. The `net.ess3` is for essentials, so you need at least Essentials.

Such as wrote [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/navycraft-lite.42297/) (on spigotmc page of plugin, you need few dependencies :

- [EssentialsX](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/9089/)
- [WorldEdit](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldedit)
- [WorldGuard](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldguard)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it doesn't seem to work... I tried to insert the latest version of every plugin you have listed into the plugins folder in my server.

Comment: You well restart ? It's the same error ? @BasZ the plugin seems old, so maybe you can download old version

Comment: It is the same error. There is a "jars" file in the open source, do I need to put these depencies there? I could try to put an old version of Essentials in my server's plugin folder tho.

Comment: Oh yes, it's a good idea, i didn't see them